# Why are my colours outputting so differently in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, rgb

Despite trying various colour profiles across Illustrator and CS5 I seem to keep running into save for web, export and screen-grabs (used as a more accurate last resort) issues where the colours I'm designing in output dramatically differently on each.

Obviously showing clients work, where the colours are far removed from my initial work, is off putting.

Any ideas on why, and ideally, how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Info: iMac -  CS5 mostly (CS6 is the same) running Lion although I doubt this matters. Also, sRGB and AdobeRGB makes no difference.

Comment: Is your Document Color Mode RGB or CMYK?

Comment: Did you check to make sure that you color settings in each program are set the same?

Comment: All RGB, and colour profiles set via bridge so it's a universal change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you save as a PNG? If your color inconsistency is solely in a browser it may be due to gamma correction. You could try and [compress](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/tools-for-lossy-png-compression) your PNG and remove all colourspace information from your PNG.  You can read more about [The Sad Story of PNG Gamma “Correction”](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/)

Comment: Interestingly the Save For Web dialogue shows a similarly different result to the PNG (i.e almost entirely different colour range) when set as JPG, however, the final outputted result is the same as the screen grab, and my view on screen in illustrator. 

It's not an ideal result but I'm happy enough that I can send like for like proofs to the client.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Just to make it a little more interesting. My PNGs are now OK too. Still not in the Save For Web dialogue but once outputted.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to redo the "color management" on your computer. I ran into this a couple years ago at work, I could save a small picture to the desktop and open it, take a screen shot of it and paste it into photoshop and the colors would be different!! I don't work there anymore so I don't have the exact settings, but I remember where I changed the settings.

Right-click your desktop then select "Screen Resolution". Click "Advanced Settings", then select the "Color Management" tab and hit the "Color Management…" button. Make sure your display device is the one selected in the drop-down and go to the "Advanced" tab. There are a few different options with how your computer will try to display certain media types. You will have to play with it to decide which works best for your monitor/computer set up.

[image]

Comment: On a Mac these days so the process is a little different. However, I've been through the colour settings before (and checked again just now to make sure nothing had changed) and the RGB is the same as my adobe profile.

= sRGB IEC61966-2.1

Frankly I had the same issue when everything was set to Adobe RGB 1998 which makes me think it's outside the colour profiles but I'm at a loss!

Comment: You would think PS on a mac would work proper... I don't know much about macs anymore, get on ,do stuff, turn it off nowadays...